# i want to connect to SQL Server using Java, please find the code below and i am getting the exception as given below "Error Message"

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

```
String dburl="jdbc:sqlserver://209.18.103.198:1433;CreditDB_V2";
  //Connecting to Database
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
 Connection con=java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,"700User","cred!tUser");
 Thread.sleep(20000);
 if (con!=null)
   {
    System.out.println("Database Connected Successfully");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rss=stmt.executeQuery("update User_LogDetail set LoginTime=(GETDATE()-   
        35), StatusId = 401 where UserId in(select userid from user_detail where UserName 
        in('sahooxml','gopal','psahoo7'))");
 Thread.sleep(30000);
  while (rss.next()) {
    Object dbtime = rss.getString(1);
    System.out.println(dbtime);
   } //end while
 con.close();
 }
 else
  {
    System.out.println("Database Failed to connect");
  }
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Login700.LoginTest(Login700.java:26)
    at Login700.main(Login700.java:242)
```

Comment: your code is correct but the driver jar file is missing in your classpath.

Comment: which jar file i have to include

Comment: here you can find it. download the tar.gz file and extract it. you can find sqljdbc.jar inside. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

Comment: Thanks Mohammad Shamsi. Now I am able to connect to DB successfully using the above code.

Comment: I am able to connect to DB but, i am not able to run the query. I am getting the Error Message as "The statement did not return a result set." I don't need to fetch any records from the DB, but i want to update the records. Can any one help me out on this.

Comment: try executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery(). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks mohammad, i have used the same executeUpdate() method. It worked. Thanks once again for ur help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jar file containing "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" class has to be in your classpath.

Comment: Martinnovoty, Can you please send the correct it and forward it to me. As I am new to Database connection using Java. I have never tried to connect using Automation. Thanks